# Jest Mock Promise with Params

Tags: node.js, jestjs, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, ssm

This is the method I am trying to write Unit test in Jest

```js
async function getParameter(parameter: string,
  withDecryption: boolean = false): Promise<String> {

  const params = {
    Name: parameter,
    WithDecryption: withDecryption,
  };
  try {
    const request = await       ssmClient.getParameter(params).promise();

    return request.Parameter.Value;
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(`Error ${err}`);
    throw Error(err);
  }
}
```

Test Method :

```js
test('getParameterFromSystemManager', async () => {
  const mockedResponseData = {
    Parameter: {
      Value: 'parameterValue',
    },
  };

 ssmClient.getParameter(params).promise = jest.fn();

 ssmClient.getParameter(params).promise.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(mockedResponseData));

 const data = 
 await SSMParameters.getParameterFromSystemManager('testurl', false, 
 'Test', 'elastic');
 expect(data).toEqual(mockedResponseData.Parameter.Value);
 expect(ssmClient.getParameter).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

I get the error :

**TypeError: 
ssmClient.getParameter(...).promise.mockImplementation is not a function**

How do we mock such .promise() functions in Jest ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this question? I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 6):

The reason why `.promise.mockImplementation` is not a function is that calling `getParameter(...)` returns a new instance/object with a new `.promise()`.

So in your first line: `ssmClient.getParameter(params).promise = jest.fn();` you only set that instance with `jest.fn()`.

In the second line you're actually calling `.mockImplementation()` on a brand new instance.

Instead you're going to have to mock `getParameter()` to make sure it returns your mock everytime.

```
ssmClient.getParameter = jest.fn();
ssmClient.getParameter.mockImplementation(() => ({
    promise: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(mockedResponseData));
}))
```